# Cannot resolve keyword 'pub_date_year'

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I followed the documentation django [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/overview/)

this my code model.py

```
    from django.db import models


# Create your models here.


class Reporter(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

class Article (models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

code urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('article/<int:year>/', views.year_archive),

]
```

code views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, render
from .models import Article

def year_archive (request,year):
    a_list = Article.objects.filter(pub_date_year = year)
    context = {
        'year' : year,
        'article_list' : a_list
    }
    return render(request, 'news/year_archive.html', context)
```

and than year_archive.html

```
{%block title%} Article For {{ year }} {%endblock%}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Article For {{year}} </h1>
{% for ar in article_list %}
    <p>{{ar.headline}} </p>
    <p>By{{ar.reporter.full_name}} </p>
    <p>Publsihed {{ar.pub_date}} </p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I want to ask
when i input urls

> http: // localhost: 8000 / article / 2020 /

error appears
*Cannot resolve the keyword 'pub_date_year'*
what should I fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [*lookup* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4) is preceeded with *double* underscores (`__`), so it should be:

```
def year_archive (request, year):
    a_list = Article.objects.filter(pub_date__year=year)
    # …
```